# Lookup hour on DateTimeField Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    inicio = models.DateTimeField()
```

When I try to make this query:

```
itens = Item.objects.filter(inicio__hour__gte=6)
```

It returns me:

> FieldError  Unsupported lookup 'hour' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted.

How can I make this query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django query datetime for objects older than 5 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345147/django-query-datetime-for-objects-older-than-5-hours)

Comment: Not duplicate, I want to filter just by hour without month, year or day.

Comment: It's the same principle. You need to filter your queryset using a timedelta, which you can extrapolate from the answer referenced.

Comment: Its diferent. I want filter just hour lookup. Not full date with year, month, day. When I use "inicio__hour__gte" it retrun "FieldError Unsupported lookup 'hour' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted."

Comment: If you know . Please answer the question with some code exemple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter using a timedelta:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

five_hours_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=5)
items = Item.objects.filter(inicio__lt=five_hours_ago)
```

You can always specify an exact datetime and then subtract 5 hours from it if you don't want 5 hours from the current datetime.

To the best of my knowledge, and according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#hour), you can only do an exact lookup on an hour, minute or second.

Comment: it's impossible make range,gte,lte ..  lookup in datetime fields. :)

Comment: This has changed as of `Django 1.9` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#hour

Answer (score 8):

Heads up, this should work as of [Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#hour)

```
Event.objects.filter(timestamp__hour=23)
Event.objects.filter(time__hour=5)
Event.objects.filter(timestamp__hour__gte=12)
```

Comment: Beware. According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#hour):
"When USE_TZ is True, datetime fields are converted to the **current time zone** before filtering. This requires time zone definitions in the database."