# Django Rest Framework Month and Year as NumberFilter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm trying to filter a model queryset in my django rest framework api and i'm getting this error when I'm using django_filters.NumberFilter(**).

If i write my own filter, I got all my results filtered, but using NumberFilter i can't make it work.

So, here's my code:
Model

```
class Entry(EntityBase):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    all_day = models.BooleanField()
    involveds = models.ManyToManyField(Person, null=True)
    by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Filterset

```
class EntryFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    #ym = MonthYearFilter(name='start')
    m = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='start__month')
    y = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='start__year')

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
```

Viewset

```
class EntryViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Entry.objects.all()
serializer_class = EntrySerializer
filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
filter_class = EntryFilter
```

ERROR

```
Unsupported lookup 'month' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted.
```

Comment: FYI: I'm just trying to filter with "exact" lookup_type

Comment: Did you check this one thread in particular? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267985/lookup-hour-on-datetimefield-django

Comment: Yeah, but here I'm exact filtering. If i query directly (queryset.filter(start__date=%s) I got the right result.

Answer (score 1):

Just update your filters this way:

```
class EntryFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    m = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='start', lookup_expr='month')
    y = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='start', lookup_expr='year')
```

You can also use __gt, __gte, __lt .. etc in your lookup expressions.

Hope it helps.