# Django Rest Framework django_filters return empty list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm trying to filter my queryset on Datefield based on year and month.
After searching a lot I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40385675/4958447) and tried to use it. but when I use filter I got and empty list.

**model.py**:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

**serializer.py**:

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = '__all__'
```

**filter.py**:

```
import django_filters # only for showing I use django_fliter not drf defult filter
from .models import Sample

class SampleDateFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    month = django_filters.NumberFilter("date", lookup_expr='month')
    year = django_filters.NumberFilter('date',lookup_expr='year')
    class Meta:
        model=Sample
        fields = ['month','year']
```

**views.py**:

```
class SampleListview(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
    queryset = Sample.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = SampleFilter
```

I have an object in my database with this config:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "date": "2020-05-03", #date format %YYYY-%MM-%DD
    }
```

without filter I got my list but  I got nothing when I use queryparam:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample/?year=2020
http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample/?month=05
```

or any combination of both filters.
I'm using:

```
django-filter==2.4.0
djangorestframework==3.12.4
Django==3.0.8
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter set is wrong.

Try this:

```
import django_filters
from .models import Sample

class SampleDateFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    month = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date__month', lookup_expr='exact')
    year = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date__year', lookup_expr='exact')
    class Meta:
        models=Sample
        fields = ['month','year']
```

Also you can use `gte` `lte` etc as expression