# Get object with specific hour in django

Tags: python, django

I have model like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    dateTime = models.DateTimeField()
```

and I want to get object with specific hour
how can I do that?
the code below doesn't work:

```
o=Order.objects.get(dateTime.hour=12)
```

and has this problem: `keyword can't be an expression`

now.. How should I give the order object with specific time?

Comment: Basically you can't write a query on `dateTime.hour` as you've only told Django that your model Order has an attribute named `dateTime`. Django doesn't know beyond that. Hence you can only write your query on `dateTime`

Comment: there isn't any way? @AnkushRaghuvanshi

Comment: this might help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345147/django-query-datetime-for-objects-older-than-5-hours

Comment: Bernie's solution should solve your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#hour

```
o = Order.objects.filter(dateTime__hour=12)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you all the objects having `hour` value as 12.

```
o = Order.objects.filter(dateTime__hour=12)
```

which can be used in place of

```
o = Order.objects.get(dateTime__hour=12)`
```

to get that one object, in case you have unique `hour` values for objects.

But if already know that you have unique value of `hour` then you should use 
the later.