# Django: annotate QuerySet with number of seconds since object created

Tags: django, date, django-queryset

I have a model, call it `Foo`, which has an attribute `created_at` which notes the time (UTC) when an instance was created. 
I would like to annotate a query set over this model with the number of seconds since each item returned was created.

(to be more precise, I would like to "discount" items based on the time they have been open, with a configurable stale-out time, but I can do that computation if I can get the number of seconds since create)

I have tried some obvious things like

`Foo.objects.annotate(time_since_create=now-F('created_at'))`

and

`Foo.objects.annotate(time_since_create=now.timestamp()-F('created_at'))`

(where `now is`utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())`)

but these get me `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'`, which suggests that DB arithmetic on dates is a little more complex than I'm thinking it ought to be.

Obviously, I can do this arithmetic in python, ie,

`[(id, now-created_at) for id, created_at in Foo.objects.values_list("id", "created_at")]`

but it would be nicer if I could get this back in the queryset.

Comment: What about `datetime.now()-F('created_at')`? Is there a reason why you want to annotate the queryset? Normally *rendering* of data is the responsibility of the template, *not* of the queryset.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in my examples, `now` is `utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())`. Editing the question to make this clear

Comment: But why do you use `.timestamp()`? Then you convert it to a `float`. What if you use `now - F('created_at')`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've tried both (see examples in the post)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the reason for annotating the queryset is because I have queryset logic downstream from this and I'd like to be able to keep it in that realm as long as possible. If this is not possible, I can make it work (as in the list comp example) but it'd be nice if I could make this work.

Comment: If you really want this to be in the queryset, then you'll need to let the database do the "unix seconds" conversion for you. The Django ORM provides no "extract function" for getting that format (like they do for __year, __month, etc), so you're stuck with a database-specific solution only.  So, are you ok with using a DB solution? If so, which DB do you want to target?

Comment: @BillHuneke That makes sense, thanks for the info. I'm using mysql

Comment: In that case, you should probably test and then accept @Durai 's answer below. That should do it for you. Obviously you'll want to remove the values() call at the end if you want to have a general purpose queryset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution you could use is extra in django queryset. You don't need to perform annotate or aggregate if you need difference for all the records.

My database is mysql. So I used TIMESTAMPDIFF in seconds. TIMESTAMPDIFF is from mysql db. You need to use the function available in your db in the below queryset. Hope this helps.

Visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#s-extra

```py
time_since_create = {"time_since_create": """TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, created_at, now())"""}
objs = Foo.objects.extra(select=time_since_create).values('name', 'time_since_create')
str(objs.query)
```

If you print the sql query, it will be something like this.

```sql
SELECT (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, created_at, now())) AS `time_since_create`, `foo`.`name` FROM `foo`
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go. If it were me I would drop the "values()" part at the end and I would use a more precise name since we're talking an integer (seconds) not an abstract (time).  So, "seconds_since_created" is more appropriate IMHO

Answer (score 0):

**First approach**

You can filter your query set like so

```
time_threshold =  datetime.now() - timedelta(munutes=40)
Foo.objects.filter(created_at__lte=time_threshold)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345147/django-query-datetime-for-objects-older-than-5-hours)

**output**

```
> <QuerySet [<Foo: 2019-11-18 20:56:16.228271+00:00>, <Foo: 2019-11-18
> 20:56:31.842079+00:00>, <Foo: 2019-11-18 20:56:32.761461+00:00>, <Foo:
> 2019-11-18 20:57:04.612091+00:00>, <Foo: 20 19-11-18
> 20:57:11.401817+00:00>, <Foo: 2019-11-18 21:00:12.794631+00:00>, <Foo:
> 2019-11-18 21:00:14.935930+00:00>, <Foo: 2019-11-18
> 21:00:59.107677+00:00>, <Foo: 2019-11-18 21:01:27.5 90956+00:00>]>
```

**Second approach**

You can create a def in your model to take the time elapsed since create
and then use it

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def time_elapsed_since_create(self):
        return datetime.now(timezone.utc) - self.created_at

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.created_at)
```

**Output**

```
>>> bar = Foo.objects.create()
>>> print(bar.time_elapsed_since_create())
0:00:09.480279
>>> print(bar.time_elapsed_since_create())
0:00:10.560474
>>> print(bar.time_elapsed_since_create())
0:00:11.248255

>>> print(type(bar.time_elapsed_since_create()))
<class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

**Function to get all of the Foos that are older than 60 seconds**

```
>>> for i in Foo.objects.all():
...     if i.time_elapsed_since_create() > timedelta(seconds=60):
...             print(i.id, i.created_at, i.time_elapsed_since_create())
...
1 2019-11-18 20:56:16.228271+00:00 0:13:12.512974
2 2019-11-18 20:56:31.842079+00:00 0:12:56.899166
3 2019-11-18 20:56:32.761461+00:00 0:12:55.979784
4 2019-11-18 20:57:04.612091+00:00 0:12:24.129154
5 2019-11-18 20:57:11.401817+00:00 0:12:17.340419
6 2019-11-18 21:00:12.794631+00:00 0:09:15.947605
7 2019-11-18 21:00:14.935930+00:00 0:09:13.806306
8 2019-11-18 21:00:59.107677+00:00 0:08:29.634559
9 2019-11-18 21:01:27.590956+00:00 0:08:01.152280
```

Comment: Sadly, this won't help me return this in the queryset.

Comment: @JonKiparsky Check the first approach just updated the code